# return string value to html in mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to put string value to my  view page
it's something like this

```
public static  class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string ItemApiURL()
    {
        return WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ItemApiLocation"];            
    }
 }
```

this will read my web config value and return the value to my view page java script

```
<script>
var itemApiUrl = @ExtensionMethods.ItemApiURL().ToString();
</script>
```

but I am getting in runtime like this
    
    var itemApiUrl = http://example.com:22273/odata/ItemQC?

as it is no quotation " "
this give me error for me
Any thought??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A javascript string needs to be quoted:

```
<script>
var itemApiUrl = '@ExtensionMethods.ItemApiURL().ToString()';
</script>
```